# Month Problems in a groupby view

Tags: list-view

Alrite so heres my issue:

Sharepoint 2010
i have inserted the following excel code into my calculated field:

=TEXT(Created,"mmmm")

so then i did a group by in my list.

THis is what it looks like:

October
        -item 8 (date i used was some random date in october, ie 10/1/2012)
November
        -item 7 (date i used was some random date in november ie 10/5/2012)

The issue here is that I wanted months to be sorted on teh current month, dynamically.

i.e
November
        -item blah
October
        -item blah

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Regardless of year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that by current month you do in fact mean ***the current month of the current year***.

Create a column called Month_Digit and hide it from the New/Edit/Disp forms and any applicable views. It should be calculated and of type Number: `=MONTH(Created)`

Do the same with a field called Year: `=YEAR(Created)`

In your view sort by Year (descending), then by Month_Digit (descending). Then Group by the text value of Month.

The problem is that `=TEXT(Created, "mmmm")` is just a text string and you cannot sort text by anything other than the collation of a given alphabet. So you need to add the numeric representation of the months.

Comment: thanks a lot!This fixes a lot of the issues, now i just need to be able to sort the group by part.

Comment: btw, i really like how u explained what i did wrong, that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Will,

Take one more calculated column and set `=MONTH(Created)` and sort the view by this column! If you have several years data as well, then you can create another calculated column for Year and first Sort desc by Year and then desc by Month!

I hope this will achieve what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar (granted its SP 2007) but just sorting by month didn't help because the list was spanning into multiple years.  I included the Abbreviated Month and Year then just grouped on that field.

=TEXT(Created,"mmm YYYY")

Hope that helps.