# Sharepoint view: group wrong!

Tags: list-view, view, grouping

I have a list with 2 field, [Date] (Datetime) and [Month] (calculated column = text(date,"YYYY/MM"), I want to group the list by Month, but Sharepoint group it wrongly! How can I fix it?

[image: sharepoint group wrong]

Comment: this post might help you http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/sharepoint-group-by-year-or-month-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by current month you do in fact mean ***the current month of the current year***.

Create a column called Month_Digit and hide it from the New/Edit/Disp forms and any applicable views. It should be calculated and of type Number: `=MONTH(Created)`

Do the same with a field called Year: `=YEAR(Created)`

In your view sort by Year (descending), then by Month_Digit (descending). Then Group by the text value of Month.

The problem is that `=TEXT(Created, "mmmm")` is just a text string and you cannot sort text by anything other than the collation of a given alphabet. So you need to add the numeric representation of the months.

Comment: I've checked this solution this morning from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51335/month-problems-in-a-groupby-view but my problem is different.

Comment: **try this link** http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2012/02/sharepoint-group-by-year-or-month-in.html